# Сравнение вводной строки на русском языке и заранее заданной

Tags: c++, строки, visual-studio-code, кириллица

Писал проект и наткнулся на проблему, что когда идет сравнение заданной строки и вводной на русском языке, то значение сравнения принимает значение false, вот простейший пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a = "Строка";
    string b;

    cin >> b;

    if (a==b) {
        cout << "Равны";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Не равны";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Если я введу в cin "Строка", то программа выдаст "Не равны", несмотря на то, что "Строка" == "Строка", хотя если попробовать тоже самое, но на английском языке, сравнение проводится успешно, как пофикисить такую проблему?

Comment: Следует использовать правильную кодировку

Answer (score 0):

Если ты используешь классическую командную строку, то сохрани исходник в OEM866. Или измени кодировку консоли на win1251.

Comment: исходник сохранил в ОЕМ866, не помогло, а кодировка консоли все время сбрасывается, плюс я для удобства открываю сразу exe-файл кода, который сам консоль открывает, так что без понятия как это сделать